# Mongoose/MongoDB GeoJSON query gives back empty result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema (Tour) which contains this property.
The location is a GeoJSON Point type.

```
location: {
      type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    },
    index: '2dsphere'
   },
```

My controller for creating a tour looks like this

```
const createTour = async (req, res) => {
   var newTour = new TourDB.Tour({
      ...
      location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [req.body.tour.loc[0], req.body.tour.loc[1]] },
      ...
   })

   newTour.save(async (err, doc) => {
      if (!err) {
         return res.status(200).send(doc)
      } else {
         return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: err })
      }
   })
```

And in the frontend I will create a new Tour with this property `loc: [this.lng, this.lat],`

This is the result in the MongoDB:

[image]

How can I make a query to get the location within a radius?

I tried with this one in my controller (for now radius and maxDistance is hardcoded for testing purpose):

```
const getTourByRadius = async (req, res) =>  {
   let coords = [];
   coords[0] = 9.825031;
   coords[1] = 48.625107799999995

   const maxDistance = 10;

   try {
      const tour = await TourDB.Tour.find({
         location: {
            $near: {
               $geometry: {
                  type: "Point",
                  coordinates: coords
               },
               $maxDistance: maxDistance
            }
         }
      }).exec()
      res.send(tour)
   } catch (err) {
      res.send(err)
   }
}
```

But now I get an empty [] back.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text for source data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your distance? In general your code should work:

```
db.tour.insertOne({
   location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [9.8238464, 47.627712] },
   cityName: "Geislingen"
})

db.tour.createIndex({ location: "2dsphere" })

let coords = [];
coords[0] = 9.825031;
coords[1] = 48.625107799999995

db.tour.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: coords },
        distanceField: "distance",
        spherical: true
     }
   }
])
```

Returns:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("608a73d51ef0d7c449c3e4c6"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            9.8238464, 
            48.627712
        ]
    }, 
    "cityName" : "Geislingen", 
    "distance" : 302.71595482740787
}
```

Using maxDistance > 302.7 meters returns the document:

```
let maxDistance = 303
db.tour.find(
   {
      location: {
         $near: {
            $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: coords },
            $maxDistance: 303
         }
      }
   }
)

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("608a73d51ef0d7c449c3e4c6"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            9.8238464, 
            48.627712
        ]
    }, 
    "cityName" : "Geislingen"
}
```

Note, specify the distance in meters if the specified point is GeoJSON and in radians if the specified point is legacy coordinate pairs.

Comment: Indeed it was the distance... scaling the distance to like 5000 finally works for me! Wow.. Thanks :D